# Attach to Process is not working in Visual studio 2008 in Windows 7

Tags: asp.net, debugging, visual-studio-2008, iis

Today i had a wired issues with Visual Studio 2008 SP1 running in Windows 7 32bit Machine with IIS7 installed.
I am developing a web application. I have set up the default website in local host in IIS (IIS 7.0) to run the website and it is working fine when i press F5,the process runs and show break point locations. But when I try to debug the site by selecting attach to process from debug menu and select the browser process (IE8 or Mozilla), nothing happens and the process doesn't hit the break point. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Please check if you have compilation errors.

Answer (score 4):

You should attach to the IIS worker process (w3wp.exe).

Comment: I tried attaching with IIS worker process (w3wp.exe) but still i am having issues.the process doesn't hit the break point.

Comment: Your breakpoint isn't in the global.asax file is it? It's not really possible to catch some of the events (such as the app start) in the global file.

Answer (score 1):

Check you have build the process in debug mode and pdb files are deployed with dll's.

Go to Project Properties > Build Tab > Click Advanced button >Now Set Debug Info to "Full".

In the Web.config file, change the line that reads

`<compilation debug="false"/> to <compilation debug="true"/>.`

[How to: Attach to a Running Process, VS Express Edition does not allow attaching a process for debugging](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6wf8e4z.aspx)

Comment: I have checked and found the process are in debug mode and pdb files installed.Still i have issues.